# VuePress builds broken html with invalid adresses to assets

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, documentation, documentation-generation, vuepress

I'm getting broken `index.html` after `vuepress build docs` with lots of `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in console.

`vuepress dev docs`, however, works totally fine!

My steps:

1. Created new project with vue-cli 3;
2. Made `yarn add -D vuepress`;
3. Added folders and files:

```
   -docs
       |
       --.vuepress
       |         |
       |         --config.js
       |
       --guides
       |      |
       |      --README.md
       --info
       |     |
       |     --README.md
       |
       --README.md
```

My config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'Hello VuePress1',
    description: 'Just playing around',
    themeConfig: {
      nav: [
          { text: 'Home', link: '/' },
          { text: 'Guide', link: '/guide/' },
          { text: 'Вернуться в приложение', link: '/desktop/' }
        ],
        sidebar: [
            '/',
            '/guides/',
            '/info/'
        ]

    }
}
```

Now, `vuepress dev docs` gives at `localhost:8080` exactly what i expect - everything is fine.

`vuepress build docs` generates `dist` folder, which contains:

- assets folder
- guides folder
- info folder
- 404.html
- index.html

Problem arises on opening `index.html`. Everything is displayed without CSS and links are not working. Seems like problems with paths to assets...

Why everything doesn't work properly out of the box in a completely new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paths to the CSS and JS files in `index.html` are absolute (starts with `/`), so viewing `index.html` using the file protocol doesn't work (you need to host it on a server so the HTTP protocol are used).

Answer (score 0):

you must run http server to open this file.

open cmd in this folder, and run:

1. with python: python -m http.server
2. with nodejs:

- Install http-server by typing npm install -g http-server
- Change into your working directory, where yoursome.html lives
- Start your http server by issuing http-server -c-1